# How to deserialize JsonResult with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, datacontractserializer

i have an MVC Controller that returns:

```
public JsonResult ValidateUser(string siteId, string userName, string password) 
{
            UserObj userObj = new UserObj();
            userObj.Name = userName;
            return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userObj), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in the client I have:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
stream.Copy(ms);
var text = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

They output text is: "{\"Name\":\"Peter\"}"

When trying to deserialize the value Name is null.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserObj));
var resultUser = obj.ReadObject(stream) as UserObj;
```

I found that the issue is in the backslashes.. any clue on how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userObj), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

with:

```
return Json(userObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...!! you are totally right So dumb I am :)-.-. Appreciate Darin.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? Is there something else you would like to ask or you might consider closing this thread?

Comment: Everything perfect!! Thanks Darin. Just clicked the Accepted Check Mark. :) Again thanks!